# Sybase passing list of values in 1 parameter

Tags: sybase

Is it possible ?
CALL "DBA"."stored_proc"("iParameter" = 'value1','value1','value1','value1','value1')
Or how to make this possible

Answer (score 0):

Parameters must be given a system datatype (except text or image) or a user-defined datatype. I don't think there is a datatype that can hold a list of values.

However, you can use a default parameter that include a wildcard (%) - if the procedure uses the parameter with the like keyword.

For example, you can create a procedure to display information about the system tables if the user does not supply a parameter, like this:

```
create procedure showind4 
@table varchar(30) = "sys%" as 
select table_name = sysobjects.name, 
    index_name = sysindexes.name, 
    index_id = indid
from sysindexes, sysobjects 
where sysobjects.name like @table 
and sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
```

Alternatively you can pass the suitable parameters for a query that returns this list of values and then create a temporary table (inside the stored procedure) and fill it with the list of values with a `select into` query. For more on temporary tables in stored procedures see [here](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1251e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/44635;pt=44635;lang=el#X)